# Differentiate variables

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

```
var gridArray:Array = new Array(7);
   gridArray[0] = [4,2,1,1,2,3,1];
   gridArray[1] = [2,2,1,4,2,1,2];
   gridArray[2] = [1,2,1,2,1,1,2];
   gridArray[3] = [2,2,2,5,1,1,2];
   gridArray[4] = [1,2,2,1,1,1,2];
   gridArray[5] = [1,1,2,2,2,2,2];
   gridArray[6] = [2,1,2,3,1,1,2];

    for (var i:int=0; i<gridArray.length; i++)
    {
      for (var u:int=0; u<gridArray[i].length; u++)
      {  
        var tile:MovieClip = new Tile();
        tile.gotoAndStop(gridArray[i][u]);
        tile.x = (u-i);
        tile.y = (u+i);
        addChild(tile);
      }
    }

tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseover);
```

So above is in a for loop that generates a grid. It is in a Class called Main. The movie clip Tile has 5 frames, which contains different things. I have a variable called hp in the Tile class, where I assign a number.

```
if (currentFrame == 1)
{
  hp = 10;
}
else if (currentFrame == 2)
{
  hp = 20;
}
else if (currentFrame == 3)
{
  hp = 30;
}
else if (currentFrame == 4)
{
  hp = 40;
}
else if (currentFrame == 5)
{
  hp = 50;
}
```

I  trace the hp of the tiles, by using a roll over mouse event, but I am only getting 10 as a result(which means it's on frame 1), even though my array has the different frames. Below is my mouse over function

EDIT:

```
function mouseover(event:MouseEvent)
            {
                trace(event.currentTarget.currentFrame, Tile.hp);
            }
```

How can I trace each individual tile? I was thinking of adding currentframe to Tile.hp, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Where do you set currentFrame? Why do you have both currentFrame and currentFrameLabel?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited it/

Comment: if your doing that conditional in your Tile constructor, that might be the problem. Try making another method of Tile and call that after you call tile.gotoAndStop(...). Also, your conditional could just be changed to : hp = currentFrame * 10; ...